# Form not sending file when submitted with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

I have this form:

```
           <label for="pdffile">Upload</label>
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" name="upload" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="file" id="pdffile" style="display:none" form="upload"
          </form>
```

It is supposed to be submitted with this jquery:

```
$('#pdffile').change(function() {
    $('#upload').attr("action", "/upload").submit();
});
```

However when I check in PHP, nothing is uploaded:

```
dd($request)
```

Always gives me back `null` instead of the requested item.

Any help?

Comment: Your `<input>` doesn't have a **name** attribute or a closing angle bracket.

Comment: Just check that you have specified enctype in your form tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input does not have name

```
<input type="file" id="pdffile" style="display:none" form="upload"
```

change to

```
<input type="file" id="pdffile" style="display:none" name="upload"/>
```

and in your action you can use `$_FILES` to get upload file

Comment: you can just get the file from the `$request` object, no need to access `$_FILES`